Is MIK stud compatible with Ortlieb QL3.1? (pannier attachment format)
A few years ago, Ortlieb introduced the QL3.1 attachment system for their panniers. Instead of relying on two hooks that attach to an horizontal bar, and another hook on the lower end of the pannier, it relies on 3 studs protuding from the side of the rack, and panniers are simply clipsed on the studs. Big bike brands (Canyon, Orbea, Moustache to give a few names) are proposing bikes with racks that are compatible with this format (generally custom racks for given models of bikes). The promise is easier mounting and more stability.
MIK (an organism that develop "specifications/standards" for rack accessories, such as child seats) recently announced a system that is very similar to Ortlieb QL3.1: MIK Studs. The promise would be to have more choice of bags, from different brands with this style of attachment (for now, only BASIL has panniers), as MIK only licenses their specifications to other brands.
Are the MIK Studs and Ortlieb QL3.1 compatible?

I asked the support of MIK about it, the reference triangle that defines the position of the studs is identical, they use the same bolts, but the studs have different dimensions. In other words, it's possible to mount MIK Studs on an Ortlieb QL3.1-compatible rack (or the other way around), but for the bags, it's necessary to make a choice if the intent is to have several bags and choose the bag depending on the use: only Ortlieb or MIK Studs, as changing the "standard" would require to change the studs as well.
